# Have nosetests ignore minimum coverage if exit due to test failure?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

On my test runner to determine if a git branch passes or fails, I test my python like so:

`nosetests -x --with-coverage ${PACKAGE} --cover-min-percentage=80`

The `-x` (exit on first failure) is a new addition, as we want to immediately fail the build if any unit tests fail. However, if an early test fails and we exit, nosetests falsely says that min coverage has not been met if some of the early packages have low coverage because it wasn't able to cover everything.

How can I have the coverage check be aborted/ignored if any tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have the coverage check be aborted/ignored if any tests fail?

Use `coverage` to invoke `nose2` or `nosetests` where `-F` in `nose2` means fail fast same as `-x` in `nosetests`.

```
coverage run /usr/bin/nose2-2.7 -s tests -F --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml -C --config nose2.cfg.2 --verbose --junit-xml
```

Only report if the tests above succeed or exit code is `2` which is failed due to coverage less than threshold. exit code of 1 will be skipped.

```
coverage report -m
```

and/or the `.coveragerc`

```
[report]
fail_under 80.55
precision 2
skip_covered False
```

https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1a/config.html